# Grid.Background ImageBrush is not loading from local file

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to set the background image of a pages main grid.

The default:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"></Grid>
```

What I want to do:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="what should go here?" />
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

I've tried

```
ms-appdata:///local/Path/To/Image.png
```

and

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Packages\MyApp\LocalState\Path\To\Image.png
```

Neither of these work. If I put a solid color in, it works. I've even tried creating a converter that I pass these values into, and create and return a `Bitmap` of the `Uri`, but that doesn't help.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This started working, as is, and I unfornattely don't know why. I'm doing it on a different computer, so it may have something to do with that specific computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

To Set background as Image you need to include the image file into the project.
Then you need to code like below,

```
<Grid.Background>
     <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/YourImage.png"/>
</Grid.Background>
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: The app downloads the file after it's running. Will WinRT allow me to write to the apps folder? I didn't think that was an option, and doesn't seem like a good practice either.